# Переменная в SQL-запросе

Tags: php, запрос, mysql

Имеется определенный инпут-бокс с кнопкой:

---

```
<form method="get" action="index.php">
<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
<input type="text" name="para">
</form>
```

---

И имеется SQL-запрос:

---

```
<?php
$id = (int) $id;
$query=mysql_query("select * from `Определение_смены` where     `Определение_смены`.`Идент.Номер`='$id'");
{ 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo "Номер: ".$row['Идент.Номер']."<br>\n";
echo "Дата:".$row['Дата']."<br>\n";
echo "Смена:".$row['Смена']."<br><hr>\n"; 
}
}
?>
```

---

Необходимо, чтобы переменная была `Идент.Номер`='$id', которую сервер бы брал из инпут-бокса. Может кто подсказать, как такое совершить?

Comment: Не совсем понял, что нужно сделать, но, видимо, так?    
if ((isset($_GET['para'])) and ($_GET['para']!=''))    
 {    
   $id=intval($_GET['para']);    
   // запрос и все остальное    
 }

Comment: Необходимо, чтобы переменную сервер брал из инпут-бокса. 
   

А при нажатии клавиши – выполнялся запрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="get" action="index.php"> 
<input type="text" name="id"> 
<input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>

<?php

$id = intval($_GET['id']);

?>
```

Comment: Прошу прошения, но не совсем понятно. Зачем тестировать его в phpmyadmin? Запрос рабочий, я уже проверял ранее. А запрос не выдастся, так как не указана переменная.

Comment: Попробуйте так, как описано выше.

Comment: А, вот теперь вижу. Ага. Просто у меня был другой name указан, да вот и не видел. Спасибо, теперь все работает.

Comment: name можно и так name="para", просто <input type="submit" ...> должен идти после <input type="text"...>. Само значение id в этом случае:
<?php

$id = intval($_GET['para']);

?>